# DAX: Métrica seleccionar un campo en función del valor de otro en Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo un dataset con varias Ids agrupadas por países y cada Id tiene varias revisiones mensuales. Hay un único registro por cada revisión. Para seccionar el valor de un campo numérico para una revisión en concreto uso esta formula que puedo agregar por país o mostrarla por Id.

```
Income (FY20 P07) € = CALCULATE(avg(FACT_Complete[Income STD €]),filter(FACT_Complete,FACT_Complete[Revision]="FY20 P07"))
```

El problema lo tengo cuando tengo que trabajar con un campo de texto. ¿Como puedo seleccionar el valor de un campo en función de la revisión?
Y puedo filtrar la página del informe o un objeto visual con esa doble condición, ejemplo:

Filtro=>`Id's que su [Stage]="on" en el campo [Revision]="FY20 P07".`

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Saludos. Si te refieres a agregar mas condiciones a la parte `WHERE` del `FILTER` usa el `&&` que será el `Y`; es decir sería `filter(FACT_Complete, FACT_Complete[Revision]="FY20 P07" && FACT_Complete[Stage]="on")`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sería un poco más complicado, ya que necesito me devuelva todas las revisiones de los Ids que cumplan esta doble condición. Así devuelve únicamente la revisión (fila) del mes FY20 P07 de estos Ids